# Discord Error: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a problem with my code
Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'message' is not defined

```py
async def delrole(ctx, *,role_name):
  author = discord.Guild
  server = message.guild
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.send_message.server.roles, name=role_name)
  if role:
    try:
      await bot.delete_role(ctx.send_message.server, role)
      await bot.say("The role {} has been deleted!".format(role.name))
    except discord.Forbidden:
      await bot.say("Missing Permissions to delete this role!")
  else:
    await bot.say("The role doesn't exist!")
```

Comment: If memory serves right, `message` is under the context, so `server = ctx.message.guild`.

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'server'

Comment: That's a new error entirely (because you fixed the first one). The `roles` can  be found under `ctx.guild.roles`. You might want to read through the documentation for discord.py

Comment: I fixed but now i have another problem ;-;

Comment: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'delete_role'

Comment: Read through the documentation, there are more than one error here. Google will also help you ;-)

Comment: About delete_role in google i don't found.

Comment: It's covered in the documentation (and you can find it through Google too) - I'm not here to step-by-step troubleshoot your code.

Comment: Trust me i've been trying to fix it for two hours.I searched the net for all the solutions.

Comment: this is create role, i'm want Delete

Comment: You know, you can search through the documentation yourself, but here you go https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.delete

Comment: Hmm if i put await bot.delete(role.server, role) i receive error Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'delete'
if i delete bot, only delete(role.server, role) i receive error Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'delete' is not defined

Comment: Hint: The `role` class has that method, as explicitly stated in the manual.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: You need to call the `delete()` method on an object of the `role` class. I suggest you get a basic grasp of object-oriented development, and have a look through the manual to understand how its documented - and what objects have which methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean this up a lot by using a [role converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters), though that requires moving some code into an [error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)

```
@bot.command()
async def delrole(ctx, *, role: discord.Role):
    name = role.name
    try:
        await role.delete()
        await ctx.send(f"The role {name} has been deleted")
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send(f"I could not delete the role {name}")

@delrole.error
async def delrole_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.ConversionError):
        await ctx.send("I do not recognize that role!")
    else:
        raise error
```